# How to achieve smooth Hotspot Focus in panorama

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, 360-panorama

Since Last 2 days I am trying to achieve smooth hotspot focus but i am not able to achieve it.

please click on below link and click on panorama icon,you will get an idea what i am saying.
 http://ggnome.com/samples/pano2vr_5/tower/

PS: I have used http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html panorama to achieve desired functionality.

Can anyone help me with this please...

Answer (score 0):

You either have to create a 3d object in your scene and make it clickable or add a second threejs renderer, this time it will be a css3drenderer, basically it allows to have html elements in your threejs world. Place the camera in the middle of a cube made by html/css elements:

http://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/threejs/css3d/

or go completely with css, something like:

```js
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
 
 console.log('clicked on .cube. New transform: ');
 var newTransform = "translateZ(800px) rotateX("+Math.round(Math.random() * 360)+"deg) rotateY("+Math.round(Math.random() * 360)+"deg) rotateZ("+0+"deg)";
 console.log(newTransform)

 $('.cube').css({
  "transform": newTransform,
  "-webkit-transform": newTransform,
 })
});

$('video').on('ended', function () {
 console.log('ended')
  this.load();
  this.play();
});

var mousedown = true;

/*$(document).on('mousedown', function() {
 mousedown = true;
})

$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
 mousedown = false;
})*/

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
 if (mousedown) {
  var posx = e.clientX;
  var posy = e.clientY;
  var startposx = 0;
  var startposy = 0;
  
  var newTransform = "translateZ(800px) rotateX("+ (startposx + posy * -1) +"deg) rotateY("+ (startposy + posx) +"deg) rotateZ("+0+"deg)";
  $('.cube').css({
   "transform": newTransform,
   "-webkit-transform": newTransform,
  })
  /*
  startposx = posx;
  startposy = posy;
  */
 }
})
```

```css
/* scene wrapper */
.wrapper{
  height: 300px;
  margin-top:50px;
  position:relative;
  perspective: 800;
  -webkit-perspective: 1600;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  perspective-origin: 50% 1000px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 1000px;
  -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 1000px;
}

/* cube wrapper */
.cube{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 2000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(1000px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0);
  transform-origin: 1000px 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 1000px 1000px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 1000px 1000px;
  /*transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;*/
}

/* outer cube */
b{
  position:absolute;
  width:2000px;
  height:2000px;
  display:block;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:2000px;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  /*transition: all 1s linear;*/
}
b video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
    background: black;
}
b img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
}
b.back{
  transform: translateZ(-1000px) rotateY(180deg);
}
b.right{
  transform:rotateY(90deg) translateX(1000px);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
b.left{
  transform:rotateY(270deg) translateX(-1000px);
  transform-origin: center left;
}
b.top{
  transform:rotateX(90deg) translateY(-1000px);
  transform-origin: top center;
}
b.bottom{
  transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateY(1000px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
b.front{
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(1000px);
}
b p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    color: white;
    z-index: 9;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
          <div class="cube">
            <b class="front">
               <video id="sourcevid" autoplay loop controls>
                    <source src="video/BigBuckBunny_640x360.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="video/BigBuckBunny_640x360.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                </video>
                <p class="face">FRONT</p>
            </b>
            <b class="back">

                <img src="http://www.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4139/Bali-Sunset-ipad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_1024.jpg">
                <p class="face">BACK</p>
            </b>
            <b class="top">
                <img src="http://www.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4139/Bali-Sunset-ipad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_1024.jpg">
                <p class="face">TOP</p>
            </b>
            <b class="bottom">
                <img src="http://www.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4139/Bali-Sunset-ipad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_1024.jpg">
                <p class="face">BOTTOM</p>
            </b>
            <b class="left">
                <img src="http://www.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4139/Bali-Sunset-ipad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_1024.jpg">
                <p class="face">LEFT</p>
            </b>
            <b class="right">
                <img src="http://www.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4139/Bali-Sunset-ipad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_1024.jpg">
                <p class="face">RIGHT</p>
            </b>
          </div>
        </div>
```